# Mensaje `React.createClass is deprecated` al crear un componente

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un componente `Box.jsx` que a su vez requiere otro componente `InputBox.jsx` y todo esto se renderiza en un `main.jsx`. Resulta que `Box.jsx` sí renderiza pero al parecer no esta renderizando correctamente `InputBox.jsx`. No tengo ningún error en la consola del cmd.

**Box.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var inputBox = require('../boxes/inputBox.jsx');

var Box = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <inputBox/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Box;
```

**inputBox.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var inputBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div className="row">probando</div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = inputBox;
```

El resultado en el navegador es el siguiente:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="container">
  <inputbox></inputbox>
</div>
```

La consola del navegador me da el siguiente error:

```
Warning: inputBox: React.createClass is deprecated and will be removed in
 version 16. Use plain JavaScript classes instead. If you're not yet
 ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in
 replacement.
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad lo que ves no es un error, sino una advertencia que se agregó desde [React 15.5.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html), ya que `React.createClass` será removido en la versión 16. Las opciones que te aconsejan es usar clases js, para lo cual tu código quedaría como:

```
function inputBox(props) {
  return(
    <div className="row">probando</div>
  );
}
```

o usar el módulo `create-react-class` (disponible en npm) como reemplazo, lo que quedaría:

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var inputBox = createReactClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div className="row">probando</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer, es crear componentes con esta sintaxis:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'

export default class inputBox extends Component {{

  render () {
    return (<div className="row">probando</div>)
  }

}
```